# django multiple photo upload per entry

Tags: django, django-models, file-upload, django-forms

I want to let the user upload text, a describtion and multiple images per entry. But at the moment I create a new entry for every photo, instead of having multiple images for one entry. What do I have to change. Thank you.

models.py

```
class MultipleImage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    describtion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    images = models.FileField()
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MultipleImage
        fields = ['title', 'describtion', 'images']
        widgets = {
            'images': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    form = CommentForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        images = request.FILES.getlist('images')
        for image in images:
            MultipleImage.objects.create(images=image)
    images = MultipleImage.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'images': images, 'form':form})
```

index.html

```
   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
        {{field}}
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

Comment: You don't need to change anything. Is fine like this.

Comment: The upload of all fields works but if I for example upload 2 images, a describtion and a title at a time then two entries are created instead of one entry with two images one describtion and a title. Maybe it helps to understand when I say that the upload should look similar to an ecommerce website. A few photos per product, one title and one describtion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create two models, one for the `Product` and another one for `Image`. In a 1:N relationship. One `Product` has n `Image(s)` and an `Image` is for a `Product`:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    describtion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField()
```

The form:

```
   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
        {{field}}
        <input type="file" name="images" multiple />
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
    {% for img in images %}
    <img src="{{img.images.url}}" alt="Image">
    {% endfor %}
```

The view:

```py
def upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save()
            images = request.FILES.getlist('images')
            for image in images:
                ProductImage.objects.create(image=image, product=product)
            images = product.productimage_set.all()
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

        images = []
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'images': images, 'form':form})
```

Also evaluate to use third party specialized packages.

*disclaimer: I wrote the code here, not tested*

Comment: Ok thank you very much but could you tell me what to change in forms.py. Do I have to create two different classes one for Product and one for ProductImage there. In addition I have to define them in views.py and in the html form seperatly right?

Comment: OK thank you so much. One last question what do I have to change in forms.py because now there is  ```model = MultipleImage``` but I don't have it anymore